# Extract rows with unique value in one column and equal to text "NA" in another column using R

Tags: r, row, unique, na

Given a data.frame with 3 columns, A, B, C:

```
A    B       C
P   NA   black
W    4   white
F    6   black
R   NA    pink
H    8    blue
V   NA  yellow
```

Using R, I would like to figure out how to extract rows with a unique value in column C **AND** text "NA" in column B.

So in this case, the row being extracted should be row 4 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subset(dat, !duplicated(C) & !duplicated(C, fromLast=T) & is.na(B))
#   A  B      C
# 4 R NA   pink
# 6 V NA yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column `B` stores strings `"NA"` do this

```
dat[ave(rep(1,nrow(dat)), dat$C, FUN=sum)==1 & dat$B=="NA",]
```

if it stores actual `NA` values (missing values), do this

```
dat[ave(rep(1,nrow(dat)), dat$C, FUN=sum)==1 & is.na(dat$B),]
```

where `dat` is your dataframe. The result:

```
  A  B      C
4 R NA   pink
6 V NA yellow
```

Comment: Nice, but `t` is used for the extremely common `t`ranspose function - could you change it to `dat` or something similar? Also, `is.na(dat$B)` may be more appropriate if the data is actually an `NA` rather than the text `"NA"`. This is admittedly unclear in OP's question.

Comment: I have the bad old habit of using `t` myself as a short for `table`, changed to `dat` anyway. As to the `NA`s, it's already mentioned in the answer because it's unclear as you say.

Comment: Whoops, missed the second `is.na` answer.

Comment: Gotta love people who downvote you just because you point out their answer is wrong